# How to configure OBIEE 12c Authentication with external java application and bypass username and password? in BI Suite?

Tags: java, integration, business-intelligence, weblogic12c, obiee

I have a j2ee application and use database authentication and authorization to do stuff.
Also, I have Oracle BI 12c and it has separate authentication to work with it.
I can't use LDAP Authenticator for some reason and after some search about it, I think SAML 2.0 Authenticator is a good option.
can you suggest any guidance to do it?
if this solution is suitable, how to display OBIEE analytics in the external application.
I think **iframe** is a good option. but is this HTML tag support validate security tokens for sign in?

sorry about my English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not SO best practice to just post links, but the questions is so high level, that is pretty much boils down to: Did you rad up on any of this before posting? The more specific the question, the better the answer.

https://blogs.oracle.com/cealteam/obiee-web-sso-with-adfs-idp-samlv2

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Enterprise%20Performance%20Management%20and%20Business%20Intelligence/2248571_1.html

http://www.ateam-oracle.com/integrating-obiee-11g-into-weblogics-saml-sso/